# Coins distribution

Tags: combinatorics

> Some coins are distributed among 4 people A,B,C and D. In how many ways can they be distributed such that the product of the number of coins with the 4 people is 1050?

To me, because $1050 = 2*3*5*5*7$, the result, I think, should be $$480 = C_5^4 * A_4^4* C_4^1$$ which means to select any 4 of the 5 numbers (i.e. $C_5^4$) and do permutations (i.e. $A_4^4$), the other one can then be assign to any of them (i.e. $C_4^1$).

However, the result turns out to be 640. Can anyone explain why it should be 640?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe somebody gets $2$ $5$'s. The person who does can be chosen in $4$ ways. For each choice, the person who gets a $2$ can be chosen in $4$ ways, and for each of these ways the person who gets a $3$ can be chosen in $4$ ways, and then the person who gets a $7$ can be chosen in $4$ ways, for a total of $(4)(4^3)$.

Maybe the $5$'s are split. The people who get them can be chosen in $\binom{4}{2}$ ways, and then the rest of the primes can be distributed as before in $4^3$ ways, for a total of $\binom{4}{2}4^3$.

Add.

Comment: I don't get it. For somebody get $2$-$5$'s, if the person who gets a $2$ can be chosen in $4$ ways, then the person who gets a $3$ can be chosen in $3$ ways in stead of $4$ because the first person has been determined already. Right?

Comment: Not true. People can get more than one prome. For example, look at the product $(1)(2\cdot 5\cdot 5)(1)(7)$. Here A got none of the primes, B got lots of stuff, C got nothing, D got 3.  Every splitting of the product $1050$ between A, B, C, D corresponds to a decision about which of $2,3,5,5,7$ A got, B got, C got, D got. It is distributing the "presents" $p,q,r,r,s$ between $4$ people.

Comment: Thanks. I forget the case that one can have zero prime, i.e. $1$.

Comment: You are welcome. It looked as if that might be the problem.